# Replace white spaces in strings in a pipe in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following in PowerShell:

```
 $objects = git -C "$localRepoPath" verify-pack -v (Get-ChildItem "$PackFiles\pack-*.idx")`
  | Select-String -Pattern "blob"`
  | Select -First 5

  # Output each line
  $objects | % {
    $_.Line
   }
```

When I run the above I get:

```
1ff0c423042b46cb1d617b81efb715defbe8054d blob   2518 701 5081449
dc9a583bf4927685d9ceb3f9381b6a232a609281 blob   2390 1203 5082150
876f3b37e51d0af2d090104e22352171eca12bff blob   11 40 5083353 1 dc9a583bf4927685d9ceb3f9381b6a232a609281
3faa5832a9e087a5d4cf2b493c52f97eda478242 blob   21 51 5083393 2 876f3b37e51d0af2d090104e22352171eca12bff
15a0d10cde33f1d3fe5c2acda9fc1eb52def6dc6 blob   62 92 5083444 3 3faa5832a9e087a5d4cf2b493c52f97eda478242
```

I would like to replace one or more of the white spaces in the above output with '___' in the same pipe. I have tried:

```
  $objects = git -C "$localRepoPath" verify-pack -v (Get-ChildItem "$PackFiles\pack-*.idx")`
  | Select-String -Pattern "blob"`
  | % { $_.Line -replace '\s+', '___' }`
  | Select -First 5

  # Output each line
  $objects | % {
    $_.Line
   }
```

But the output is empty. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Your command work fine for me.

Comment: Forgot to include the output part, corrected the post.

Comment: remove `.Line` in the last `%` loop and you'll get your output